# Specifying the id when creating a node with the official Python embedded bindings for Neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j

Is it possible somehow? If not, what is the recommended way to deal with custom ids. Should I create an index with my custom ids?

Is there any Python client for Neo4j that handles this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should handle custom IDs using an exact matching index. Neo4j owns its IDs and will generate them for you. The only time you can set them is when you are using the BatchInserter, I don't think the Python bindings are supporting that one yet, though.

Comment: I thought of just using custom IDs initially but was not sure it was the right way. Now I know, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Perhaps you can also use an AutomaticIndex for that if you already know the name of the key you are using for storing the custom ID.